# Check if device connect to internet or not

Tags: android, internet-connection

I try this code to check if the device connected to the internet or not, Work correctly if device connected to any WIFI network or any internet provider but when connected to wifi network but this network not have internet connection. work correctly in all cases , how to solve this issue.
 This is my code

```
 public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain a little better? All I read is that this code works **correctly** all of the time

Comment: ping some public host, if no reply - not connected. you can't infer internet connectivity from wifi/lan connection status

Comment: @codeMagic if my device connected to any wifi network but this network have limited connection, the code work correctly.
the problem is code check if connect to network or internet provider or not, but not check if internet connection exist or not

Comment: Assuming I understand you correctly, go with the advice from @mangusta

Comment: Convert it as a service. Then broadcast it on network chance. It currently seems to work, but converting as service you can mánager ad handle better i think